# Evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^{3}-n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{60}+\frac{1}{120}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^{3}-n}\right)$$

I am not able to find any technique to proceed. It might be simple but I am not able to understand. If the hint and the concept used is explained it will be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Since:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)n}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{n^3-n}
$$
We have:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^M\frac{1}{n^3-n}=\sum_{n=2}^M\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)n}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{M(M+1)}
$$
So the limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Also worth to mention is that this is a **telescoping** sum. An important concept that can be used to simplify the calculations of many series.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Ákos' answer:

$\begin{align}&\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac 1 {n^3-n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)n}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)\\
&=\frac 1 2 \left[ \left(\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 6 + \frac 1 {12} + \cdots \right)-\left(\frac 1 6 +\frac 1 {12} + \cdots \right)\right]\\
&=\frac 1 2 \times \frac 1 2=\frac 1 4
\end{align}$